# Disable gzip compression in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gzip

I need to test my web application without using any http compression(disable gzip,deflate).I am able to do it in firefox using config screen,now i want to do same for google chrome.

Is there any way to disable `gzip` compression in Google chrome browser?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Chrome doesn't seem to expose this setting, but what you can do is the following:

- get the ModHeader plugin for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en (or any other that allows you to fiddle with your browser request headers)
- set a new custom header `accept-encoding` to either:

  - an empty value or
  - `gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0` either should work

Comment: an empty value worked for me, "gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0" did not work using chrome v85