# Getting junk/jumbled/encoded response from RESTservice

Tags: java, rest, internet-explorer, http-headers

I am able to hit a rest service successfully and get the response properly when I use REST client and Junit test case. But, however,when I try to hit the same rest service via IE browser, I am getting some junk/jumbled/encoded response from the rest service.I have used wireshark tool to investigate.

When I try to access the rest service via browser, the following headers are additionally added  by the browser

`accept-encoding=gzip`, `Content-Encoding=gzip`

The above headers are not added when I try using REST client or Junit test case.

I suspect that the above headers are the root cause for getting encoded response. If my assumption is true, is there any way to get rid of those headers?

I have already tried with the following, but not working:

```
'accept-encoding': 'gzip;q=0,deflate,sdch'
'accept-encoding: identity'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the headers you use when you use the REST client? It could be that browser is not setting the headers your Rest service requires.

Comment: @afrin216 Nope..It's not the problem of the headers I use. The problem is just because of the culprit header "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate" which is added automatically by the browser. I have verified using wireshark tool. Do you have any suggestions for getting rid of the header "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate"?

Comment: It does look like you've tried both the ways to disable `accept-encoding`. If you are hitting the REST service from your browser for testing purposes, why not disable these headers in the browsers themselves?

Here's a link that can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398022/disable-gzip-compression-in-chrome