# Disable Chrome's gzip automatic decompression

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gzip, tar

Recently, I have been dealing with a issue on `Chrome` that made it not possible to save correctly a compressed `gzip` file.

The root problem is described in this post: [Downloaded Gzip seems to be currupted (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68097469/downloaded-gzip-seems-to-be-currupted-chrome)

As described in the link, the file is correctly downloaded in Firefox, because the blob that the `AJAX` response receives, is gzip encoded, and therefore correctly saved as `.gz` file. But when the blob data is received in Chrome, it is automatically decompressed, obtaining plain text (`UTF-8` encoded) instead of the `gzip` encoding that we are looking after. This makes the saved file to be corrupted, because it is being saved a `UTF-8` encoded blob in a file that is supposed to be gzipped.

After some research, I finally found which was the cause of the problem: Apparently when `content-encoding: gzip` header is specified in the server response, Chrome automatically decompresses the file, assuming that the main reason of using the `gzip` compression, is only due to saving bandwidth purposes. This problem is more thoroughly described in the following post: [Chromium: prevent unpacking tar.gz](https://superuser.com/questions/940605/chromium-prevent-unpacking-tar-gz?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In that post `gzip` compression is enabled to wrap a `.tar` file, however in my case, there is not a file beneath the gzip compression ( I directly write data to the `gzip` file in the server side, using `gzip python module`). Thus, when `Chrome` decompress the `gzip`, there is only plain text. I have tried to explicitly send the response without specifying the `content-encoding` header, but it seems that Chrome automatically detects the encoding.

Is there anyway that I could disable Chromes's `gzip` automatic decompression?

Comment: Brief clarification included. Hope it helps!

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19425303/1533592

Answer (score 0):

Answer. set a new custom header accept-encoding to either: an empty value or. gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0 either should work.