# Downloading and saving .tar.gz file using ajax and fs in electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, electron, node.js-fs

I am trying to include auto-update feature in my electron app but I am struggling to download and save a .tar.gz file for the latest release using GitHub API. Here is relevant code snippet:

```
// check for new version
$(document).on("click", "#check-updates", () => {
  $.get('https://api.github.com/repos/PATH_TO_REPO/releases/latest')
    .then((r) => {
      // check if version tag is newer than current version
      if (r["tag_name"].slice(-6) <= current_version.slice(-6)) { 
        $("#check-updates").html("No updates found.");
      } else {
        release_to_download = r;
      }
    })
})

// download update
$(document).on("click", "#download-new-version", () => {
  for (let asset of release_to_download["assets"]) {
    if (asset["content_type"] == "application/x-gzip") {
      console.log(`Downloading from ${asset["browser_download_url"]}`);

      $.get(asset["browser_download_url"])
        .then((data) => {
          fs.writeFile("release.tar.gz", data, 'binary', (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
              console.log("Update downloaded")
            }
          })
        })
    }
  }
})
```

However when using the above I cannot open downloaded .tar.gz file - I get "File is corrupted or wrong format" error. When I follow the `asset["browser_download_url"]` in the browser I can download the file perfectly.

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong? Anything I could do better? Thanks!

Comment: Some browsers will decompress .tar.gz files automatically.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112512/disable-chromes-gzip-automatic-decompression

Comment: @James if that is what's happening, how do I proceed? I cannot set the "accept-encoding" header as the browser build into my electron project treats it as 'unsafe' and refuses to set it to advised values. I do not have the access to the server-side, since I am using github API. Anything else I could do?

Comment: I have never tried this.  It looks like you can add extraHeaders to a request, see https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/3227.  However that might not be possible via jQuery get