# Why is the HTTP responses inside my .pcap encrypted or unreadable? How do I fix this?

Tags: python, http, pcap, tcpdump

I am trying to troubleshoot a Python script and figure out what is happening with the HTTP requests and cookies and responses the script is getting.  I used tcpdump -w to capture the data, and it appears the website is sending back some kind of compressed response.  Yet, if I copy the exact cookie details and URL and put it into Fiddler, this doesn't happen.

Why or HOW do I stop the output from being compressed and unreadable?

```
GET XXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (QtEmbedded; U; Linux; C) AppleWebKit/533.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) MAG200 stbapp ver: 4 rev: 1812 Mobile Safari/533.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: application/json,application/javascript,text/javascript,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: Keep-Alive
Referer: XXXXX
Cookie: stb_lang=en; timezone=America/Toronto;
X-User-Agent: Model: MAG254; Link: Ethernet

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2023 15:16:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=Cf%2B1Seanoyi9p6Z0LGYFEl%2FRx2eH4nP8Qvr3VK7CoHEA3h7QI9nk0bj9xjE6MmlB0RCMq0P9tho71KjzU4ox8%2FEo7SdW0DiaWkv4TfP1TFwD1cOdqxcFWx6CEwBfgUjJWozwbA5u14LgBbwg"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 7d5292aca9292c48-ORD
Content-Encoding: gzip
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

d1
..........L.Kn.0.....f.U.O..US.5*..6.`.mP+...@..v......-.qB..V{.6..8..;5.^.R.~.........|B...z)7.Dr6.Y.8 e..\d1  vL.(.t.....E.#.....o......a....?9q  .gX..z!....W.?..55....b........zZ.....\J....._............i....
0
```

tcpdump -w

I was expecting the .pcap to show the response from the server in a readable format, not compressed or "chunked"

Also, when I copy and paste these exact headers and cookies line by line into Fiddler, the results are NOT scrambled up like this.

So why is this happening?

Comment: The headers clearly indicate `Content-Encoding: gzip`, which is pretty typical. Tools like `requests` will handle that for you automatically. If you're relying on wire capture, you could look at e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398022/disable-gzip-compression-in-chrome) for how to instruct the remote site to *not* use gzip encoding.

Comment: Fiddler has the same content-encoding: gzip line in the headers, copied word for word, and the output is in plain text and I can view the JSON and server response.  There is nothing different between what I am passing in Fiddler, and through Python.  So somewhere along the way something is not matching up, and I don't understand why Fiddler isn't compressing it but Python is

Comment: The output from a wire capture with `tcpdump`, or the output you see in Fiddler? Because fiddler -- like most other http clients -- probably transparently supports gzip encoding.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why Fiddler isn't compressing it but Python is

Neither Fiddler nor tcpdump are compressing anything.  The *server* sending the reply is compressing it; Fiddler is *de*compressing it, but tcpdump is just writing out raw packet data to a pcap file, and whatever program produced the output you're showing didn't decompress it, probably because it doesn't have code to decompress it.

Wireshark, however, *does* include code to decompress gzipped replies; try reading the pcap file with Wireshark.

Note also that it says "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"; that's ["chunked transfer encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), and that will also complicate the task of processing the transferred content.  Fiddler may "de-chunk" the data, and Wireshark also includes code to de-chunk data.

This all means that the Python script, or any libraries it uses to perform HTTP requests and parse HTTP responses, will need to include both code to decompress gzipped data and de-chunk chunked data.  If the script itself is processing the response, it will need to have code added to it to do the decompressing if the HTTP response headers indicate a gzipped content encoding and de-chunking if the response headers indicate gzipped transfer encoding.  If it's using a library to do HTTP, then the library will need to have code to handle gzipped content encodings and chunked transfer encodings.

Another possibility, if the code you're using to do HTTP supports it, is to follow larsks's suggestion and tell the server that you don't support gzipped or chunked encodings, in the hopes that the server will just send you the reply in uncompressed form without using chunking.